How to use the features hyperlink, blockquote, preformatted text, insert citation to make my question more clear
I have had the issue of needing help with a question in math text articles or book and I always used image of a screenshots I took using ifran. But problem is they never came out clear enough so that others could really help as I can understand as if I tried to scrutinize the same myself I would just become exasperated and not want to bother reading that question. so now I have the articles and books myself as files usually .pdf. So why the interface does not give one the ability to upload a file. Can I and if so how could I use hyperlink, blockquote, preformatted text, inset citation links to upload and paste or whatever the pertinent parts of the articles and books that I have? I cannot put in any hyperlink or can I? I don't have any website of my own but I do have email. I don't suppose I could in anyway use that. What do 'blockquote, preformatted text, insert citation' really mean anyway and could I make use of them to help and if so how? Also how could I use anything to paste parts or portions of my .pdf files in a clear way.

This might be useful - to some extent: What tools can be used to extract MathJax/LaTeX from scanned input? (So that the asker does not have to retype everything.)

Also related: Can I upload a pdf file along with a question/answer? and How could I attach a pdf file?

There is no automation to cut and paste portions of a PDF file into a post on StackExchange. If a file exists on the Internet, with some restrictions you can post its URL as a hyperlink for your Readers.
As you've described, images can be uploaded to StackExchange and (hyper)linked in the body of a Question.  If an article can be found on the Internet, then you can provide a link to it in your post.  This is a basic feature of Markdown used in formatting posts. It corresponds to the "links" symbol in the tool menu between italics I and quotes $\mathbf{"}$.
The other toolset you'll want to become familiar with is MathJax /$\LaTeX$.  See here for a brief introduction and the tutorial/quick reference for more detailed info.
These last tools allow you to produce typeset quality math notation in your posts.  While slower than plain text typing, it is adequate for the portion of posts that require such notation (formulas, matrices, etc.)

If what you are trying to insert is a (reasonably short) purely text
file, where the fixed-width spacing is important, such as with programming code or pseudocode, the edit bar includes a preformatted text text icon, which will insert 4 spaces at the start of each line.
This causes the insertion to be shaded, with its fixed width spacing preserved.
Alternatively, if you wish to have your posted question refer to a pdf file or a lengthy text file, you should be able to find a free storage provider, which will allow you to upload your file and store it on the internet, without cost.
Once this is done, you can simply provide a link to the (internet available) file, directly in your posted question.

no what i have is not a text file . And storing was not the question or issue but anyway those free storage providers are not guaranteed to do it free and unchanged etc. from now to god knows when and assuming i may not ever contact them or anything for many many years also i would bet.
